# Why is there a delete option for answered questions?

Tags: discussion, support

Wouldn't it be better if there was no option to delete a question that cannot be deleted? Why is there a link there to delete when it cannot be used?

Comment: Show a example.

Comment: Do you mean on a question you yourself have posted?

Comment: **This should be on Meta.SO since this hapens network-wide. This is for the ecosystem of EE.SE and it's problems that don't apply to more than 1 site, Meta.SO is for SO.SE questions like that and also for bugs, improvements, and support for all sites.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One advantage to showing the delete button regardless is that it gives you more detailed feedback on the reason you can't delete it. For example a while back I posted an answer and the first half solved the OPs question, so he accepted it but the second half contained something false / misleading as pointed out in a comment.

Unfortunately it was when I was heading off to bed and the next morning a better answer had been posted so I thought I might as well delete mine and got something like "an accepted answer may not be deleted". That was clearer than the delete button not being present and I knew to edit the incorrect part of my answer rather than delete it.

Also as Olin pointed out in a comment for Meta posts it's best to mention a particular question or answer you have in mind if you're after a specific reason on why it can't be deleted.